# What are the most common project formats for modern NLE software?

Tags: video-editor, file-formats

For my [sound syncing tool](http://auxmic.com) I'd like to implement saving project to file which will be suitable for most modern non linear editors. I try to avoid looking into each proprietary format of major vendors, because some of them are closed binaries.

Surprisingly there is only Apple provides clear description of its [XML-project format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FinalCutProX/Reference/FinalCutProXXMLFormat/Introduction/Introduction.html).

So far I know about these formats:

1. Advanced Authoring Format (AAF)
2. Open Media Framework Interchange (OMFI/OMF)
3. Edit decision list (EDL) - plaintext

Are there any other common XML or plain-text based project formats to transfer between different software applications?

Comment: Those are the three I've ever worked with.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the three that are industry standard, XML is a useful one to include though because Final Cut (which oddly is still highly utilized in the industry) uses it.  Also XML can easily talk between all Adobe applications and Da Vinci.

Comment: Premiere also allows you to export footage as an XML, making it play nice with other programs.

Comment: It isn't that odd it is still used, it just shows how many people don't like being locked in to having to pay whatever the competition asks to stay in business. (Ala Adobe CC)

Comment: The question was not in reference to whether or not XML is useful or not, but rather as to what the most common NLE file formats.  And if we ignore that the better majority, well not the majority, almost all professional editing is done with AVID (by professional I am not referring to the guy who does wedding videos, but rather the guy who cuts feature films with distribution and commercials) then yes, XML is a commonly used file.  But since XML does not talk with AVID, or any of the Autodesk software, or Pablo, and quite a few others, I would say no, it is not a common NLE file format

Comment: Autodesk doesn't have an NLE other than a basic one in Smoke, so I don't find them not supporting XML to be an issue.

Comment: But they support AFF and EDL, I am not saying they need to, but again I am simply answering the question that was asked